# kdb5_ldap_util: Kerberos Container create FAILED: Loop detected while creating realm 'EXAMPLE.COM'

Tags: ldap, kerberos

I'm trying to connect my Kerberos server to an LDAP storage, but I'm getting this error:
**kdb5_ldap_util: Kerberos Container create FAILED: Loop detected while creating realm 'EXAMPLE.COM'**
when i try to create the REALM with this command :

`kdb5_ldap_util -w secret -D uid=admin,ou=system create -subtrees ou=system -r ${KRB5_REALM} -s -H ldap://${LDAP_URI} -P admin`

this is my /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
rdns = false
default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = krb5_host
    admin_server = krb5_host
    default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
    database_module = openldap_ldapconf
}
[dbdefaults]
    ldap_kerberos_container_dn = uid=admin,ou=system
[dbmodules]
openldap_ldapconf = {
    db_library = kldap
    ldap_kdc_dn = "uid=admin,ou=system"

    # this object needs to have read rights on
    # the realm container, principal container and realm sub-trees
    ldap_kadmind_dn = "uid=admin,ou=system"

    # this object needs to have read and write rights on
    # the realm container, principal container and realm sub-trees
    ldap_service_password_file = /etc/krb5kdc/service.keyfile
    ldap_servers = ldap://ldap_host:ldap_port
    ldap_conns_per_server = 5
}
```

this is my LDAP tree

[ldap tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQydX.png)

I'm still new to this so Thank you for any help :)